# Locking formula values in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

### Question

I'm trying to make a google sheet for calculating my net income over a set period of time. I have all the things but one thing figured out. That one thing being, I don't know how to lock a value in a formula to make it say the same for when I select and copy the cell formula to other cells. I'm very new to google sheets (and any form of excel) so I don't have much idea as for what I'm doing. Some help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance. If my question wasn't very clear or needs rewording please let me know and I will work to correct whatever it is that is unclear.

Edit

So I've been doing some searching and working on the sheet, and I've decided to drop one of the things I was going to do because it didn't make much sense. So now the situation is that I need to have a value *change dynamically* as I continue to add more rows. What I'm trying to do now is have the cell formula change to add together the cell, say B3, and the cell above it, B2, and have that stored on another cell. I don't really know how to go about doing this, so any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance and sorry for the sudden change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDITED***

Based on your edited statement with *`...need to have a value *change dynamically* as I continue to add more rows. What I'm trying to do now is have the cell formula change to add together the cell, say B3, and the cell above it, B2, and have that stored on another cell`*, I suppose this is what is your goal  **(feel free to correct me if I'm mistaken)** :

***Example:***

> [image]

- **Used `=SUM($B$2:B)` on cell `C2`:**

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Hey, so I found something out about google sheets, that being, new data from google forms is appended to the end of the sheet. so if you look at the edit i made just a few minutes ago you can see the new problem I have. I appreciate the help none the less

Comment: @SentBySunlight I have updated my answer, I hope it answers your question. Feel free to let me know if I have missed anything.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried what you showed above and it worked, so again thank you so much for all of the information you have given me. Thanks to you I am a much more capable user of google sheets. I cannot say thank you enough, I truly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just copy the value and paste, I believe that is CTL+SHFT+v.  If you want to copy the formula and paste it so that it refers to the same cells when it's copied, then you need to change the references so that they are static.  For instance, if the formula refers to A1 and you copy it one column over it will change to A2, and if you copy it one column over and one row down it will change to B2.  If the formula refers to $A$1, it will always refer to A1.  You can do this manually, or you can highlight the cell reference and press F4 to change it to a static reference.

Hope I understood the problem correctly.

Comment: Hey, appreciate the help, but i ended up figuring something out. that being that google sheets appends new entries through google forms to the sheets file. In hindsight this does make a lot of sense. sorry for the change, this has been a learning journey for me. I will probably end up using this info later in my project though, so your efforts have not gone to waste. I appreciate the help and if you think you know how to do what I talked about in the edit, I would love to hear your solution. Thanks again